# can i interface profinet protocol to ethernet interface?

Tags: ethernet, protocol, network-interface, profibus

i have a profinet device and an Ethernet port which is dedicated for KNX protocol. can i connect my profinet device to this Ethernet port?

Comment: Sure you can connect them at Ethernet level, but the KNX device won't start talking profinet. Are you trying to use it like an Ethernet switch or something like that?

Comment: From my knowledge the KNX physical layer is not ethernet, while the profinet has the same layer as ethernet, so that ethernet port is a profinet port and you connect a PLC or profinet master.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič: I think he is talking about KNXnet/IP.